# SwfObject not setting bgcolor in IE

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, background-color, swfobject, param

I am trying to create a flash object using SwfObject javascript. It how ever works well with FF and chrome, but it doesnt display the background colour

---

### My JS Code

```
 var swfWidth = "500";
 var swfHeight = "500";
 var swfBgColor = "#ff0000";

 var flashVersion = '9.0.0'
 var flashvars = false;
 var params = { bgcolor:swfBgColor };
 var attributes = {};

 swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrl, "kcSwf", swfWidth, swfHeight, flashVersion, "/resources/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, attributes, params);
```

---

### This is the output that it gives on my IE for the above code.

It does set the **bgcolor** property on the  **tag**, however it doesnt set the bgcolor in the  **tag** (see below)

```
<OBJECT style="VISIBILITY: visible" id=kcSwf classid=clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000 width=620 height=540 bgcolor="F8F8F8"><PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="16404"><PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="14287"><PARAM NAME="FlashVars" VALUE="">
 <PARAM NAME="Movie" VALUE="http://test.skf.com/CampaignBanner/knowledgeengineering/090309_banners/flash_example.swf">
 <PARAM NAME="Src" VALUE="http://test.skf.com/CampaignBanner/knowledgeengineering/090309_banners/flash_example.swf">
 <PARAM NAME="WMode" VALUE="Window"><PARAM NAME="Play" VALUE="-1">
 <PARAM NAME="Loop" VALUE="-1">
 <PARAM NAME="Quality" VALUE="High"><PARAM NAME="SAlign" VALUE="">
 <PARAM NAME="Menu" VALUE="-1">
 <PARAM NAME="Base" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="AllowScriptAccess" VALUE="">
 <PARAM NAME="Scale" VALUE="ShowAll">
 <PARAM NAME="DeviceFont" VALUE="0">
 <PARAM NAME="EmbedMovie" VALUE="0">
 <PARAM NAME="BGColor" VALUE="">           // <--- check this
 <PARAM NAME="SWRemote" VALUE="">
 <PARAM NAME="MovieData" VALUE="">
 <PARAM NAME="SeamlessTabbing" VALUE="1">
 <PARAM NAME="Profile" VALUE="0">
 <PARAM NAME="ProfileAddress" VALUE="">
 <PARAM NAME="ProfilePort" VALUE="0">
 <PARAM NAME="AllowNetworking" VALUE="all">
 <PARAM NAME="AllowFullScreen" VALUE="false">
 <PARAM NAME="AllowFullScreenInteractive" VALUE="">
</OBJECT>
```

Answer (score 1):

:) i think that was pretty silly of my the post a question and answer it myself :)

well it was a silly issue, but may be it might just help some one some day.
I had messed up with the sequence of **attributes & params**

---

### Wrong sequence

swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrl, "kcSwf", swfWidth, swfHeight, flashVersion, "/resources/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, **attributes, params**);

---

### Right sequence

swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrl, "kcSwf", swfWidth, swfHeight, flashVersion, "/resources/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, **params, attributes**);